# How to find out to which roles have grants on certain tables?

Tags: oracle, permissions, role

I have 2 tables and I want to know what object (table) grants are assigned to a role.

Is there a way to find it out?

Comment: I want to know what object(table) grant are assigned to a role.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer somewhere else. So I need to query `role_tab_privs`.

Here is the query in case somebody else will need it:

```
select role, table_name, privilege 
from role_tab_privs
where table_name in ('TABLE_NAME') order by role;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS 
WHERE GRANTEE='<RoleName>' and table_name = '<TableName>';
```

Comment: Welcome, you could improve your answer by explaining why it works.